# White screen, header information

Tags: 7

I'm getting the following errors after I modified my custom module.

> warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/rssmgovu/public_html/blackbox.tv/BB/sites/all/modules/custom/custom.module:1) in /home/rssmgovu/public_html/blackbox.tv/BB/includes/session.inc on line 98.
>   warning: session_regenerate_id() [function.session-regenerate-id]: Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent in /home/rssmgovu/public_html/blackbox.tv/BB/includes/session.inc on line 101.
>   warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/rssmgovu/public_html/blackbox.tv/BB/sites/all/modules/custom/custom.module:1) in /home/rssmgovu/public_html/blackbox.tv/BB/sites/all/modules/custom/custom.module on line 194.

The code of my module is the following one.

```
function custom_init() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'custom') . '/js.js');
}

function custom_perm() {
  return array("register access", "access download", "access terms");
}

function custom_menu() {
  $items['user_signup'] = array(
    'title' => '',
    'page callback' => 'custom_page',
    'access arguments' => array('register access'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  $items['download-file'] = array(
    'title' => '',
    'page callback' => 'download',
    'access arguments' => array('access download'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  $items['terms'] = array(
    'title' => 'NON-DISCLOSURE AGREEMENT', 
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('custom_full_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access terms'),
  );

  return $items;
}

function custom_full_form() {
  global $user;
  $uid = $user->uid;
  $qry = db_fetch_array(db_query("select mail from {users} where uid=" . $uid));
  $sql = db_query("select fid, value from {profile_values} where uid=" . $uid);
  while ($rqy = db_fetch_array($sql)) {
    if ($rqy["fid"] == 3) {
      $ln = $rqy["value"];
    }
    else if ($rqy["fid"] == 4) {
      $fn = $rqy["value"];
    }
  }

  $form['terms']['first_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('First Name'),
    '#size' => 20,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="fname">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#default_value' => $fn
  );

  $form['terms']['last_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Last Name'),
    '#size' => 20,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="lname">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#default_value' => $ln
  );

  $form['terms']['mail'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('E-mail'),
    '#size' => 20,
    '#maxlength' => 128,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="femail">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#default_value' => $qry['mail']
  );

  $form['terms']['check'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#name' => 'terms_checkbox',
    '#title' => t('I accept the terms'),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="terms_check">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>'
  );

  $form['terms']['decline'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Decline'),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="decl">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>'
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Accept'),
    '#prefix' => '<div class="acc">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#disabled' => true
  );

  return $form;
}

// function custom_full_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {}

function custom_full_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  $uid = $user->uid;
  $last_name = $form['terms']['last_name']['#value'];
  $first_name = $form['terms']['first_name']['#value'];
  $mail = $form['terms']['mail']['#value'];
  $fid_last_id = 3;
  $fid_first_id = 4;
  if ($form_state['values']['op'] == 'Decline') {
    drupal_goto("logout");
    exit;
  }
  elseif ($form_state['values']['op'] == 'Accept') {
    $_uid = db_fetch_array(db_query("select uid from {profile_values} where fid=$fid_first_id and uid=".$uid));
    if (empty($_uid)) {
      db_query("insert into {profile_values}(fid,uid,value) values($fid_last_id,$uid,'" . $last_name . "')");
      db_query("insert into {profile_values}(fid,uid,value) values($fid_first_id,$uid,'" . $first_name . "')");
    }
    else {
      db_query("UPDATE {profile_values} SET value='" .$last_name. "' where uid='".$uid."' and fid=".$fid_last_id);
      db_query("UPDATE {profile_values} SET value='" .$first_name. "' where uid='".$uid."' and fid=".$fid_first_id);
    }
    db_query("UPDATE {users} SET mail='" . $mail . "', init='".$mail."' where uid=" . $uid);
    db_query("UPDATE {users} SET accept=1 where uid=" . $uid);
    drupal_goto("download");
    exit;
  }
}

function download() {
  $filename = $_GET['file'];
  header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
  $ending = end(explode(".", $filename));
  if ($ending == 'air') {
    header('Content-Type: application/air');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  }
  else {
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . substr($filename, 15) . '"');
  }

  watchdog("downlaod", $filename . " was downloaded");
  readfile($filename);
  exit;
}

function custom_page() {
  return "";
}

function custom_login_forgot_password() {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'user') . "/user.pages.inc";
  include $path;
  return drupal_get_form("user_pass");
}

function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "user_login_block") {
      $item = l(t('Lost your password?'), 'user/password/forgot', array('attributes' => array('title' => t('Request new password via e-mail.'))));
      $form['links'] = array('#value' => $item, '#weight' => 10);
      $form['submit']['#value'] = '';
      $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_login_submit';
  }
  elseif ($form_id == "custom_full_form") {
    $form['terms']['first_name']['#title'] = "";
    $form['terms']['last_name']['#title'] = "";
    $form['terms']['mail']['#title'] = "";
  }
}

function validateFormSubmit() {}

function custom_login_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  $sql = db_fetch_array(db_query("select accept from {users} where uid=" . $user->uid));
  if ($sql['accept'] != "" && $sql['accept'] != 0) {
    header("location:/BB/download");
    exit;
  }
  else {
    header("location:/BB/terms#content");
    exit;
  }
}

/*
function custom_user_register_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  user_module_invoke('validate', $form_state['values'], $form_state['values'], 'account');
}
*/

function custom_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
  global $user;
  $block = array();

  switch ($op) {
    case 'save':
      break;

    case 'list':
      $block['custom_user_login']['info'] = t("custom User login");
      /*$block['custom_user_register']['info'] = t("custom User register");*/
      return $block;
      break;

    case 'view':
      if ($delta == "custom_user_login") {
        if ($user->uid == 0) {
          $block['subject'] = t("");
          $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('user_login_block');
        }
      }
      /* elseif ($delta == "custom_user_register") {
        $block['subject'] = t("");
        $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('user_register');
      }*/

      return $block;
      break;
  }
}

function custom_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['block']->delta == "custom_user_login") {
    $vars["template_files"][] = "block-custom-user";
    $vars['block']->htmlid = "block-custom-login";
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug this yourself at all?  What did you try?

Comment: yeap i have tried a lot, compared with my local file, no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the error message, you can see

> output started at ... /custom.module:1

You have some manner of output at the top of your file. Have you pasted the file exactly as it is written? If so, it's probably an encoding problem, possibly a so called [BOM-character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Try re-saving the file in just ascii format.